# Bluedragon 7.1 Application.cfm being called for all pages, not just cfm pages

Tags: iis, iis-7, coldfusion, bluedragon, application.cfm

All our current webservers are of the following configuration:
IIS 6.0
Windows Server 2003
Bluedragon 6.22

We recently were told to upgrade to windows server 2008. In order to do this, we had to upgrade to Bluedragon 7.1 and IIS 7.0

The issue we are having is the application.cfm file is being called for ALL pages/files in our web-application, and not just CFM pages. Thus, HTML/CFM tags are being injected into .js and other types of files causing them to not function.

Does anyone have any clue how to configure this?? Application.cfm should only be called for CFM pages

Comment: How are you determining that Application.cfm is executing for non-cfm pages? "_HTML/CFM tags are being injected into .js and other types of files_" What do you mean? The Application.cfm file would not "_inject_" CFML tags into files.  Can you show us examples?

Comment: he is most likely using his application.cfm as a template wrapper, while not ideal, it is one way save duplication on site-wide wrapper markup.

Comment: The way I was able to tell...is the application.cfm page has some <!--- ---> style comments in it, as well as a <head><body> tag in it. Now..when I try and access my site, it fails on a javascript error, so I used chrome to spy the js file and it had those comments and <head><body> tags in it. So as an additional test I put a test.txt file on the web.server with just "asdf" in it, and when I access that file...it has asdf...then the comments/tags from application.cfm

Comment: See @WalterBax answer, check your IIS Handler Mappings. Do you have a wildcard mapping pointing to the Bluedragon servlet?  Compare your upgraded server's settings to your original server's settings.

Comment: I appear to have dug myself a deeper hole. I noticed the "working" server didnt' have bluedragon handler mappings for the 4 coldfusion file types, so on the "not working" server I went to remove one and it removed all 4 at the same time, with no type of "undo" functionality :(

Comment: How could the "working" server work without any handler mappings? Did you remove the mappings from the site level or server level? If the site level then just modify the web.config file to get them back (it should inherit from the server level). Do your servers have the Bluedragon module in IIS? [See the screenshot from this page](http://www.davemineer.com/index.cfm/2012/11/13/Removing-bluedragon-from-one-iis7-website)

Answer (score 0):

I would first check your Handler Mappings under your IIS Manager, at the Server level and then the Site level to be sure that you are only attaching the cfm handler to the file types you wish.

Comment: At the server level, bluedragon has no handler mappings. At the site level, it has 4 for *.cfc, *.cfchart, *.cfm and *.cfml